# FontWeight attribute doesn't work [Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime]

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

The case is really trivial: FontWeight's attribute for `TextBlock` does not work in Universal Store App. I have created sample project (Universal App), and in the WindowPhone's `MainPage` added `TextBlock` styled like that:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize=20
           FontWeight="Thin"
           Text="Test text should be thin in runtime." />
```

In the designer everything looks fine, but when I deploy an app on a simulator/device, test text is not thinned! It's normal. Check out the screenshot:

[image: SS from VS2013]

As you can see, in the designer the text is perfectly thin (it's beautiful!). However in the running simulator text's weight is normal. Why's that? How can I workaround it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works pretty well in WP8.0 Silverlight but in WP8.1 run time, you'll need to apply a `<Style>` to it as well.  Like so

---

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="Test text should be normal in runtime."/>

        <!-- apply the a style like BodyTextBlockStyle -->
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"
             Text="Test text should be thin in runtime."
             FontWeight="Thin" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

[image]

Comment: You've got to be f-kidding me.. Thank you very much! I have just two quick questions. 1. Why is that, why do I need to apply that style? 2. How the heck did you come up with that solution? I spent hours trying to workaround it, but it never crossed my mind to try and apply some 'random' style.

Comment: @Malutek, I actually worked backwards to solved your problem.  Most of the TextBlock in my application had a Style already associated with it.  So it worked for me the first time around.  So I just did the difference of your code vs mine and it was the addition of the Style that made it work and not work.  You can use any style you want, I just picked the BodyTextBlockStyle.

Comment: I see. What you're saying it's interesting, because in my original code I also have `Style`s applied to different `TextBlock`s. Adding another `Setter` to a certain `Style` failed to work (in runtime). But inherting after `BodyTextBlockStyle`(BasedOn attribute) did the trick. So I think it's not 'any' style, what matters is that's one of the default `Style`. Thanks once again!